# JSON Deserialization Despair (unable to deserialize nested types)

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

There are probably 500 questions like this on SO, and a million websites out there all offering tidbits of information - but I just can't see the wood for the trees. This seems like it should be embarrassingly simple to do, but I just can't make it work.

I have a WCF webservice that returns a serialized JSON object:

```
[OperationContract(Name = "PeopleData"), WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "people/{subset}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
PeopleObject GetPeople(string subset);
```

This works - if I hit that URI from a browser, GetPeople is invoked and returns a JSON-serialized `PeopleObject` (actual data values redacted for privacy here):

```
{"HashValue":"XXXXX","People":[{"EmailAddress":"XXXXX","EmployeeID":99999,"Gender":"X","JobTitle":"XXXXX","Office":"","PreferredName":"XXXXX","Surname":"XXXXX","WorkExtensionNumber":"XXXXX","WorkPhoneNumber":"XXXXX","Department":"XXXXX","DeskNumber":"XXXXX","EmploymentClassification":"XXXXX","InternationalExtensionNumber":"XXXXX","IsFirstAider":false,"Languages":[{"LanguageID":9,"LanguageSkillID":9},{"LanguageID":9,"LanguageSkillID":9}],"QualificationInitials":"XXXXX","QualificationTitle":"XXXXX","Secretaries":null,"WorkMobilePhoneNumber":"XXXXX"}],"RecordCount":"1","SizeBytes":"12345"}
```

In this example the `PeopleObject` payload contains just one `Person` object in the collection, but could contain many (depending on the parameter supplied in `/{subset}`.

Here is the class hierarchy for `PeopleObject` - it's a top-level container holding some metadata about the payload, and a List<> of `Person` objects. Those objects in turn have a bunch of simple type attributes, plus two further nested List<> of `Language` and `Secretary` objects (which may or may not be populated):

```
  [DataContract]
  public class PeopleObject
  {
    [DataMember]
    public string HashValue { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Person> People { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string RecordCount { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string SizeBytes { get; set; }
  }

  [DataContract]
  public class Person
  {
    [DataMember]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    // <-- snip - lots of fields like this, no point listing them all here
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsFirstAider { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Language> Languages { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<Secretary> Secretaries { get; set; }
  }

  [DataContract]
  public class Language
  {
    [DataMember]
    public int LanguageID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int LanguageSkillID { get; set; }
  }

  [DataContract]
  public class Secretary
  {
    [DataMember]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public char FirstSurnameLetter { get; set; }
  }
```

So far, so good - WCF responds with a JSON structure that contains all the fields and their contents. Now to deserialize that structure in a client application (using the same class hierarchy definitions):

```
  // I have a little helper-class to manage the WCF request and return a Stream
  using (Stream response = wcfHelper.GetRequestResponseStream(MY_WCF_URI))
  {
    // This is debug code to prove the response arrives as expected - it does
    //StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response);
    //Console.WriteLine("\nResponse:\n{0}", sr.ReadToEnd());

    // Deserialise the response
    DataContractJsonSerializer dc = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(PeopleObject));
    PeopleObject p = (PeopleObject)dc.ReadObject(response);

    // The object shows 1 record (in the example) but nothing in the List<>
    Console.WriteLine("\nDeserialized records: '{0}' [{1}]", p.RecordCount, p.People.Count);
  }
```

So this correctly deserializes the container object, giving me the record count, hash value, and payload size in bytes. The object does also have a List<> of Person objects, but it's null - the content from the JSON response hasn't successfully rehydrated the List<> by creating and adding a Person object.

What am I missing? My understanding was that this rehydration of the C# object hierarchy from the JSON structure should happen automatically, so either that's not the case (and I need to write some code to make it happen) or it is, but I've missed something obvious.

Comment: Stab in the dark: "enumeration types can be marked with the DataContractAttribute attribute, in which case every member that participates in serialization must be marked with the EnumMemberAttribute attribute. Members that are not marked are not serialized." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731923.aspx

Comment: @jbabey I think that's referring to `enum` types, not enumerable types like `List<T>`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908209.aspx You need to give it a list of all the child types as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done what you are doing before, but judging by the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908209.aspx), I'd assume the following would work:

```
List<Type> types = new List<Type>();
types.Add(typeof(Person));
types.Add(typeof(Language));
types.Add(typeof(Secretary));

DataContractJsonSerializer dc = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(PeopleObject), types);
PeopleObject p = (PeopleObject)dc.ReadObject(response);
```

You basically need to tell the Serializer all the types it may encounter while serializing/deserializing your object.

Comment: Son of a...

Yep. Nailed it. You rock.